# A Literary Build Puzzle

Tags: wordplay

In this puzzle, every clue leads to a title of a book by a famous author.  However, due to a mass breakout of printers' demons, each book title has been changed by one, and ONLY one, letter.

As an example, if the clue were "Over four dozen colors of animals YOU can hunt!" the answer would be "50 Shades of Prey," based off "50 Shades of Grey," by E.L. James. (This author applies for this example ONLY.)

In these 10 clues, the author is the same for ALL answers.

How many of them can you solve?

1. Dr. Freud receives assistance developing his theory of the human psyche.
2. Dr. Freud documents a young man's distaste for the letter "D."
3. A smuggler hides from the Empire by posing as a poultry farmer.
4. A farmer develops a solution to the rodent problem in his barn.
5. Reflections on the operation of toilets in London.
6. A young man recounts his memory of seeing his father assaulted by a policeman.
7. A book touting the wonders of working from home during the 1980's.
8. A survey of military bases in America.
9. A diner special featuring an indeterminate number of ocean perch.
10. A primer on computer programming.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The author is

> Dr. Seuss

```
1. Dr. Freud receives assistance developing his theory of the human psyche.
```

> Horton Hatches the Ego [Horton Hatches the Eg**g**]

```
2. Dr. Freud and his assistant document a young man's distaste for the letter "D."
```

The answer, from Chris Cudmore:

> The 500 (D) Hate of Bartholomew Cubbins [The 500 Hat**s** of Batholomew Cubbins]

```
3. A smuggler hides from the Empire by posing as a poultry farmer.
```

> Green Eggs and Han [Green Eggs and Ha**m**]

```
4. A farmer develops a solution to the rodent problem in his barn.
```

> The Cat in the Hay [The Cat in the Ha**t**] (The Borax [The **L**orax] also works, but not as well)

```
5. Reflections on the operation of toilets in London.
```

> If I Ran the Loo [If I Ran the **Z**oo]

```
6. A young man recounts his memory of seeing his father assaulted by a policeman.
```

> Cop on Pop [**H**op on Pop]

```
7. A book touting the wonders of working from home during the 1980's.
```

Original answer:

> I Can Lead with My Eyes Shut! [I Can **R**ead with My Eyes Shut!]

Better answer (thanks to Miles in the comments):

> Fax in Socks [F**o**x in Socks]

```
8. A survey of military bases in America.
```

Original answer:

> Oh, the Places You'll G.I.! [Oh, the Places You'll G**o**!]

Better answer (thanks to Apep in chat and Timoris in the comments):

> The Fort Book [The Fo**o**t Book]

```
9. A diner special featuring an indeterminate number of ocean perch.
```

> One Fish Two Fish Red Fish Blue Dish [One Fish Two Fish Red Fish Blue **F**ish]

```
10. A child's first book about a programming language.
```

> My Book about ML [My Book About M**E**]

Comment: ^vote with a note: Please quote the lines being referenced.  (Never expected on initial post, but after a few hours . . .)

Comment: @Rob Other people are welcome to jump in with the answers to those pieces, and my answer (on 2,7,8) is subject to change at least for the next day or so.

Comment: Could 8 be "The Fort Book"? (The Foot Book)

Comment: @Timoris I think so; this answer was also suggested a while ago by Apep in the chat room, so I will edit my answer to include this.

Comment: 7: "Fax in Socks"?

Answer (score 2):

2

> The 500 (D) hate of Bartholomew Cubbins

Answer (score 1):

Alternate for 7:

> And to Think That I Sew It on Mulberry Street 
>  [And to Think That I S**a**w It on Mulberry Street]